# Join two Tables with NULL as generic data

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have two tables, one has the fact data (Table1) and other is a dimension with values for the first table (Dimension).
The Dimension table uses null as a generic value.

I know I can do a "Join" using temp tables and two updates, but I think there must be a better way.
How can I do this join?

Thanks

```
       Table1:                                Dimension:
Col1:    Code1  Code2:                Code1:       Code2:    Value
a          1      12                    1           12         5 
b          1      15                    1           15         6
c          1      16                    1           16         7
d          1      17                    1         <null>       9 
e          1      20                   


       ResultTable                           
Col1:    Code1  Code2   Value                
a          1      12      5
b          1      15      6
c          1      16      7
d          1      17      9
e          1      20      9
```

Comment: Are you wanting to include or exclude null values?

Comment: I need to include the null values. But Null values represent generic data, i.e. "all the other codes that are not already included in dimension"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a default value.  You can use two `left join`s:

```
select a.*, coalesce(b.value, bdefault.value) as value
from a left join
     b
     on a.code2 = b.code2 left join
     b bdefault
     on bdefault.code2 is null;
```

Another fun method uses `outer apply`:

```
select a.*, b.value
from a outer apply
     (select top (1) b.value
      from b
      where b.code2 = a.code2 or b.code2 is null
      order by (case when b.code2 is not null then 1 else 2 end)
     ) b;
```

Comment: Yes, assuming there's a single `null` row in the Dimension table. Should be the case anyway.

Answer (score -1):

Simplifying tables, this is one approach, Check it at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82ac8/4)

**MS SQL Server 2017 Schema Setup**:

```
create table a ( i int, a varchar(100) );
create table b ( i int );

insert into a values 
(1, 'A'),
(2, 'B'),
(Null, 'Generic');

insert into b values
(1),
(2),
(3),
(4);
```

**Query**:

```
with no_corresponding as
( select b.*
  from b left outer join a on a.i = b.i
  where a.i is null
)
select a.*, b.*
from a inner join b on a.i = b.i
union all
select a.*, no_corresponding.*
from no_corresponding cross join a
where a.i is null
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/82ac8/4/0)**:

```
|      i |       a | i |
|--------|---------|---|
|      1 |       A | 1 |
|      2 |       B | 2 |
| (null) | Generic | 3 |
| (null) | Generic | 4 |
```

Comment: Please, let a comment with your downvote. This answer is not wrong (in my opinion)